# How to unit test a stream that is returned from a function?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test, dart-unittest

**I have the below setup:**

```
class Resource<T> {
  T? data;
  String? error;

  Resource._({this.data, this.error});
  factory Resource.success(T? data) => Resource._(data: data);
  factory Resource.error(String error) => Resource._(error: error);
  factory Resource.loading() => Resource._(); 
}
```

---

```
 class CategoriesRepo{
    Stream<Resource<List<Category>>> getAllCategories() async* {
        yield Resource.loading();
        yield (Resource.error(NetworkErrors.NO_INTERNET));
      }
}
```

---

```
test('Loading then error',
      () async {
    final categoriesRepo = CategoriesRepo();
    expect(
        categoriesRepo.getAllCategories(),
        emitsInOrder([
          Resource<List<Category>>.loading(),
          Resource<List<Category>>.error(""),
        ]));
  });
```

---

**I am getting this error:**

```
test\unit-tests\screens\categories\categories_repo_test_test.dart       main.<fn>.<fn>

Expected: should emit an event that <Instance of 'Resource<List<Category>>'>
  Actual: <Instance of '_ControllerStream<Resource<List<Category>>>'>
   Which: emitted * Instance of 'Resource<List<Category>>'
                  * Instance of 'Resource<List<Category>>'
                  x Stream closed.
```

**How can I properly test the above Stream?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test itself is valid, however there is a small problem when it comes to assertion and comparision of objects. Basically `Resource.loading() == Resource.loading()` is false so the assertion fails.

Why is it false? By default Dart objects (aside from primitives) are equal only when they are **the same instance**.

To make your assertion and this kind of tests work you need to implement `==` operator and hashCode for your objects. You can do it manually, but that's a bit unproductive. A lot of people use package [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) or [freezed](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed), equatable is a bit easier as it doesn't involve code generation and is recommended by [bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/bloc) (stream-based state management) authors.

```dart
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Resource<T> extends Equatable {
  T? data;
  String? error;

  Resource._({this.data, this.error});
  factory Resource.success(T? data) => Resource._(data: data);
  factory Resource.error(String error) => Resource._(error: error);
  factory Resource.loading() => Resource._();

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [data, error];
}
```

Of course you can also just change the assertion so it no longer uses comparision of objects, but predicates and matchers, but this isn't pretty.

```dart
expect(
  categoriesRepo.getAllCategories(),
  emitsInOrder(
    [
      predicate<Resource<List<Category>>>(
          (r) => r.error == null && r.data == null),
      predicate<Resource<List<Category>>>(
          (r) => r.error == "" && r.data == null),
    ],
  ),
);
```